# CoreBluetooth identifies two peripherals as the same

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have two BLE circuit boards (custom built by my company) that are advertising. When I scan, they are identified as the same CBPeripheral despite having different names and identifiers. Here's my console readout of the delegate call:

```
centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x144d26c70, identifier = E0FE60A5-FC4A-A6C5-3868-7D0EEAA580CD, name = Board A3D43, state = disconnected>
centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x144d26c70, identifier = 2209CC24-05E8-8455-3A40-3F27AE9078DB, name = Board 51EB5E, state = disconnected>
```

My question is how are CBPeripherals differentiated, if not by name or identifier? Our firmware uses Bluetopia under the hood, perhaps there's some incomplete serialization in there?

Comment: The two identifiers and names are completely different. The memory address of the variable happens to be the same but that is meaningless anyway.

Comment: You're right. I'm getting more details on the solution, but it turned out to be related to the IRK. iOS saw the peripherals as the same in the Settings app and during connection procedures, which was causing us a lot of problems, and I thought the memory address might be a clue. Will post the solution when I have more detail.

Answer (score 2):

As Paul mentioned in his comment, the memory addresses didn't end up being relevant to this problem. The core problem was that the peripherals were generating identical IRKs, which caused iOS to mistakenly think they were all the same peripheral. The error stemmed from a false assumption that the key diversifying function (d1 in core BT spec, vol 3 part H 5.2.2.1) had a randomness component, when in fact it's just a hashing function.

We were able to verify success on this by looking at the Settings app - before the change, when we connected a new peripheral, it overwrote the previous pairing in Bluetooth settings. Once we made the IRKs unique we saw multiple devices listed in the Settings app.